# No Post Data to Controller

Tags: php, codeigniter, post

I have a simple form built in a CodeIgniter view:

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<base href="<?php echo site_url(); ?>" />
</head>
<body>

<?php echo form_open('main/testformout'); ?>
First name: <input type="text" name="fname" /><br>
Last name: <input type="text" name="lname" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

EDIT: Here is the HTML output of the form above:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>

<form method="post" action="http://www.mypage.com/main/testformout">
First name: <input type="text" name="fname" /><br>
Last name: <input type="text" name="lname" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>


</body>
</html>
```

I have tried it with and without the form helpers but in this example I am using the form_open helper.

When hitting the submit button no POST data makes it to the Controller.

Controller Code:

```
    public function helperin()
    {
        $this->load->view('test/helperin_v', NULL);
    }
    public function testformout()
    {
        print_r($_POST);
        echo "<br />";
        echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];
        echo "<br />";
                var_dump($this->input->post());
        $this->load->view('test/out_v', $viewData[$_POST]);
    }
```

When the system and application folders are loaded at the same level as the public_html folder I get this result:

```
GET
bool(false)
```

When the system and application folders are loaded inside the public_html folder (I know this is not secure) I get this result:

```
Array ( ) 
GET
bool(false)
```

Also, the code works perfect on my local machine but does not work on when uploaded to Bluehost server.

Here is my htaccess file (because I've done enough research to know this may be of value).

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|public|assets|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Bluehost service people are saying it is because of a redirect issue and they consider the matter closed but as I am not doing a redirect that leaves either the CodeIgniter framework or their server.

Comment: What is you source code printing out as? Check to see what method code igniter has used for the form

Comment: Use Firebug/Chrome Dev Tools to see where the form is being posted to, and to see if there are any redirects.

Comment: How do I track redirects in the Dev Tools?  I've got both Firebug and Chrome so instructions for either would be fine.

Comment: Press F12 key, then click Net/Network tab and then submit your form.

Comment: I'm not showing any redirects when moving from one page to the next.